# getting warning "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected"

Tags: php, oop

I am doing coding in oops for uploading image in PHP. But After submit image, it's giving warning

"Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected"

Below is my function, on which its giving error

```
public function ft_redirect($query = '') {

    if (REQUEST_URI) {

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = REQUEST_URI;

    }

    $protocol = 'http://';

    if (HTTPS) {

        $protocol = 'https://';
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {

        if (stristr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "?")) {

            $requesturi = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0, strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "?"));

            $location = "Location: {$protocol}{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}{$requesturi}";
        } else {


            $requesturi = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

            $location = "Location: {$protocol}{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}{$requesturi}";

        }

    } else {

        $location = "Location: {$protocol}{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}";

    }

    if (!empty($query)) {

        $location .= "?{$query}";

    }

    header($location);

    exit;

}
```

Comment: echo out the values being passed to `header()` and make sure they don't contain new line characters somehow

Comment: echo out value is------>                                              "Location : http://localhost/filethin/index.php?dir="                                                                                                                   But it doesn't contain any new line

Comment: I was having the same problem and it turned out to be an unset variable on the POST request method.

Comment: authenticate method should return a string not a redirect.

Answer (score 32):

You shouldn't put more than two lines in URL address. Check you URL.

```
Good URL - "http://mail.google.com"  - 1 line

Bad URL - "http://mail.              - 2 lines
            google.com/"
```

Comment: I've had this error a couple of time recently and every time it's down to a typo missing out closing quotes etc

Comment: It will also happen when you set the `header()` with the `\n`(new line characters)  in between.

Answer (score 15):

in "Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate" The method "redirectTo" should return an url path, not the Redirect response.

```
...
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if(\Auth::user()->hasRole('copy')){
        return '/copy/dashboardCopy';
    }       
}
...
```

Comment: You are a savior

Comment: ive been scracthing my head over this. thank you! `[+1]`

Answer (score 3):

This warning occurs to indicate that you might have a new line [/n] in the string content of your variables.
Example

```
  header("Location: ../control.php?post='$title1'&sample='$val'");
```

here there are 2 variables

> $title1
>   and
>    & $val

so while running if This warning occurs warning

> “Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected”

**The solution is**
 To strip out the passable new line contents of the variable Like this

```
    $val=str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $val);
    $title1=str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $title1);
```

Then you can include the variables in the header

---

The ideal way of solving it is like this

```
$url="../control.php?post='$title1'&sample='$val'";
 $url=str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $url);
 header("Location: $url");
```

** This will work 100%;**

Comment: I would say trim() is a more traditional way to deal with unwanted whitespace

Comment: `trim()` only removes whitespace characters (or other characters you specify) from the _beginning and end_ of the string. If the newline is in the middle of the string, `trim()` won't do anything to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Trouble could be in your phpMyAdmin, table wp_options, option_value.

If there is a **space** before the URL it will generate the ERROR: warning: header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the variables you are using to create the Location attribute has a new line character in them. Pass them through [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

Comment: I have echo my link. But there is no new line it. Below is link i have echod                                                                    "Location : localhost/filethin/index.php?dir="

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected" error in your Laravel application, it's often related to how you handle redirection in your authentication middleware. This error occurs when there are multiple headers being sent to the response.

In your authentication middleware, specifically the redirectTo method, avoid using return redirect()->route('somewhere') as it can lead to this error. When you use redirect(), Laravel internally adds HTTP headers for the redirection.

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        // return redirect()->route('signin');  <<<< this is bad
        return route('signin');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your URL and it should work : http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

You should put the URL "http://example.com like this , please avoid "http://example.com/" "/" does give URL Mismatch , so avoid , Same problem will comes wordpress also. So try to use like this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to add in the route

```
'middleware' => ['auth']
```

in your routes/web.php

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me when I copy/pasted the URL of my site in my PhpmyAdmin, when I intended to change wp_options URLs (siteurl and home).

I solved it by removing white spaces in my site URL at wp_options!