# Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in********************.php on line 16

Tags: php

what's wrong?! line 16 is:   header('Location: '.$get_link.'');

```
<?php

require_once("../libs/proxy.php");
require_once("../libs/config.php");
require_once("../libs/ip.php");

$rnd = intval(rand(1000,9999)); //generate random number
$lnk_lnk = "../$db_name/lnk/$userip.xxx"; //link path
$api_url = "http://btc.ms/?api=$btcms_api&url=$site_url/links/verifier.php? 
id=$rnd&format=text";
$get_link = file_get_contents($api_url);
if (!empty($get_link)) {
    $m_lnk = fopen($lnk_lnk, "w"); //open link file
    fwrite($m_lnk, $rnd); //store random value
    fclose($m_lnk);

    header('Location: '.$get_link.''); //here is line 16!
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?lnkmsg=Unknown Error.");
}

?>
```

thanks for help!
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting warning "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320403/getting-warning-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-new-line-dete)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your URL contain multiple lines. You can use the function `urlencode()` to correct this error.

Try this,

```
header('Location: '.urlencode($get_link)); //here is line 16!
```