# How to echo javascript encoded url from GET variable on php

Tags: php

How to echo-ing decoded url from GET method on php,

i have this link:

```
localhost/whatsapp?text=Hello%2C%20Who%20are%20U%3F%0AName%3A%20%0AAddress%3A%20%0AAge%3A%20
```

with this code

```php
$text = $_GET['text'];
header("Location: https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=00000000&text=".$text);
```

but get error

> Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in index.php on line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting warning "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320403/getting-warning-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-new-line-dete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you retrieve values from `$_GET`, they are *URL decoded*. If you want to pass it back, you need to encode it again, so that newlines, spaces and other weird characters gets encoded. Use `urlencode($text)` for this.

```php
$text = $_GET['text'];
header("Location: https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=00000000&text=".urlencode($text));
```

Comment: on whatsapp write as Hello,+Who+are+U?
Name:+
Address:+
Age:+ how to remove "+" char?

Comment: That's the *encoded* URL. To decode it, you use `urldecode()` on it after its sent (on the receiving end). You need to check what sort of parameter you can send to their `text`.

Comment: I want to convert from this link `localhost/wa-gen/?text=Hello%2C%20Who%20are%20U%3F%0AName%3A%20%0AAddress%3A%20%0AAge%3A%20`
to
`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=00000000&text=Hello%2C%20Who%20are%20U%3F%0AName%3A%20%0AAddress%3A%20%0AAge%3A%20` so echoing exactly same to $text, but the retrun is diffrent when i use urldecode()

Comment: I think whit urlencode() it will remove `%20` to `+` how to exactly echoing same variable without converting `%20` to `+`

Comment: `rawurlencode()` would parse spaces as `%20`, while `urlencode()` parses spaces as `+`. Might want that function instead.

Comment: Yes, Thats what i mean.. Its Work! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse the incoming encoded URL before adding the correct part to the new URL, such as:

```
<?php
    $url = 'localhost/wa-gen/?text=Hello%2C%20Who%20are%20U%3F%0AName%3A%20%0AAddress%3A%20%0AAge%3A%20';

    $newURL = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=00000000&".parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
?>
```

`Parse_url` is very good at extracting pieces from a given URL.