# Redirecting to external website with post data results in ErrorException (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to redirect my site to an external website with parameters. However when I do this, I get an Error Exception saying "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected". This would be my redirection code;

```
return Redirect::to($redirectUrl)->with(['ord_date' => $dueDate, 'ord_totalamt' => $cart_total, 'ord_gstamt' => 0.00, 'ord_shipname' => $user['name'],'ord_mercref' => $ord_mercref, 'ord_mercID' => $merchantid, 'ord_returnURL' => 'http://local.site.com/order/status', 'merchant_hashvalue' => $key]);
```

Note that I've tried using `Redirect::away` as well, and it results in the same error.
What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit #1;**

My `$redirecturl` is as such; `$redirecturl = 'https://myurl.com"` so it is in one line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting warning "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320403/getting-warning-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-new-line-dete)

Comment: different, I've went through that article before posting it here :/

Comment: `with` flashes data to the session, it doesnt append query params to a URL.

Comment: hmm that explains quite a bit. will try and look for an alternative following the answer provided below.

Comment: @UdhayanNair If the answer worked for you, mark as "the answer" to close your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should build the data into the `$redirectUrl` yourself instead of using `with`.

```php
$query = http_build_query([
    'ord_date' => $dueDate,
    'ord_totalamt' => $cart_total,
    'ord_gstamt' => 0.00,
    'ord_shipname' => $user['name'],
    'ord_mercref' => $ord_mercref,
    'ord_mercID' => $merchantid,
    'ord_returnURL' => 'http://local.site.com/order/status',
    'merchant_hashvalue' => $key
])

$formattedRedirectUrl = preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "\n", $redirectUrl);

return Redirect::to($formattedRedirectUrl.'?'.$query);
```

Comment: @UdhayanNair Then you have a bad `$redirectUrl` value with a leading space and/or a line break. Edited my answer.

Comment: That would be funny because I added another question as a duplicate which was about that error.

Comment: @Flame i know, flagged it too and as you can see, the answer evolved.

Comment: But as seen from my Edit1, my Url has no space or line break :/

Comment: @UdhayanNair do you still get the same error even with the edited solution ? can you `var_dump($redirectUrl)` and post the result ?

Comment: this would be the result of the var_dump, and yeah i still get the same error :/ 
`string(42) "https://uat.kiplepay.com/wcgatewayinit.php"`

Comment: when i dd/var_dumped `$query`, I got this as it's value;
`ord_date%5Bdate%5D=2019-09-10+01%3A42%3A30.825713&ord_date%5Btimezone_type%5D=3&ord_date%5Btimezone%5D=UTC&ord_totalamt=23.8&ord_gstamt=0&ord_shipname=Udhayan+Nair&ord_mercref=870&ord_mercID=80000155&ord_returnURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocal.site.com%2Forder%2Fstatus&merchant_hashvalue=50252b02b5c83c49440ed842544b1ce0ede2cec0`

Comment: @UdhayanNair you must be using a weird `miidleware` that adds headers to the server response.

Comment: @UdhayanNair why is the `$dueDate` and array ?

Comment: i've amended the` $dueDate` to return a string, was an array as it was in `Carbon` format. But still the same. looking into the `middleware` now.