# How to send a message with login in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

I have this function for log but I have an error in the compact

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (Auth::user()){

        $msg_modal = 1;
        return '/', compact('msg_modal');
}
```

to run this script which show me a modal

```
@if(!empty($msg_modal) && $msg_modal == 1)

<script>
$(function() {
$('#mostrarmodal').modal('show');
});
</script>

@endif
```

This is the modal that I would like to see when I log

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mostrarmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <h3><center>System</center></h3>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <h4><center>Message</center></h4>
          <center>You are connected!!!</center>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">Continuar</a>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to return error message from your controller directly:

```
return redirect()->with('message', 'Success');
```

And then you should do something like this:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<!-- your modal goes here !!! -->
@endif
```

Instead of outputting the `modal()` method, you can directly assign the show class to your modal, depending on the existing or nonexistent message from the controller.

Comment: thanks a lot!! where do I have to put  return redirect()->with('message', 'Success'); in my function?

Comment: replace your `return '/', compact('msg_modal');` with the given example :)

Comment: pro tip: you can specify your desired return path in the `redirect()`-Method

Comment: I obtained this ErrorException
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320403/getting-warning-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-new-line-dete) solves the problem? Would appreciate a vote on my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In `return '/' , compact($msg)` you return `string` so you can not pass variable with `compact`

You should use `view` for this purpose like this:

```
return view('/',compact('msg_modal'));
```

Comment: I obtained this when i return a view  InvalidArgumentException
View [.] not found.

Comment: You use [] instead of () in your code too?may i see that line which you use view()?

Comment: yes... i used this ().. and gave this error . was not found.
Did you mean home?... and when I put return view('home',compact('msg_modal'));... It gave me this error ErrorException
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Comment: When you use view('home',...) it means that in your routing you set name for your route.for example:route::get('/','HomeController@index')->name('home');   maybe you forget set name in your routing and you call it by name. Set name for route or call it with its path like this: return view('/',..);may i see your routing too?

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::get('', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');  there are my routes

Comment: Ok. As i guess your routing is wrong.you dont path anything to first argument and you left it with ".define relative oath of your route in it .

Comment: I think I have a problem in my auth because when I define a route it gave me this 404
Not Found

Comment: No.authentication error is different your error changed after set first arguement of route like i said?As you said befor you get syntax error but now 404notfound.

Comment: I put this route Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); and this is my view return view('home', compact('msg_modal')); is in there any error?